# Filtering a LARGE delimited file with AWK

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, awk, command-line

I am working with a large (20+ GB) delimited text file I would like to process in python. My current workflow, which was devised with smaller files in mind, includes a sorting step, in pandas. Reading 20+ GB into memory isn't a great idea obviously. Chunking the file isn't really applicable either since I actually need to sort the entire data...

My current strategy is to sort using GNU sort, prior to any processing. At this point I can also filter the fields I don't need, so I have the following one liner:

```
awk '{ print $37,$62,$23,$10,$53,$57,$68,$26,$52,$4,$38,$5,$24 }' ../ck_data/big.txt | gsort --parallel=8 --key=1,1 -n -o ../ck_data/sorted.txt
```

The problem here is that adding the filtering step, slows down dramatically. Sorting the whole file (without any awk) takes a bit less than 2 mins on my machine, compared with 16 mins 20 secs it takes for both processes.

Is there a way I can speed up the filtering process? I am not sure if I can utilise the cores efficiently since I have only one file to process. Right? I have had issues with subprocesses and pipes previously, is it smarter to separate the awk call from the sort, by means of a temp file?

Comment: "is it smarter to separate the awk call from the sort, by means of a temp file?". I think you would find that a tmp file solution would be even slower, because `sort` will process whatever data it can, while the records are being cleaned up. You might find loading all data into DB and the extracting from there might be a reasonably fast solution, but I don't know if you have access to a DB. Without using something like `split`, you won't be able to parallelize the pre-processing steps, and unless `split` can parallelize, I don't think that will help either. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter I could consider splitting, but I am curious what it does in the background. Without knowing the size of text per line, it cant do any counter magic to read faster than what `awk` or  `sed` manages, or am I mistaken?

Comment: If you are doing this for a production job that will run every day, then documented test cases are your best friend. (Just using 1GB of data should be enough). If you're doing this as a one off, then I wouldn't worry about the extra time. I did change/edit my thinking in my first comment, I now doubt that `split` can parallelize, but Different OS's have different features, so you might find that as a feature somewhere. So I'm "voting" that there is not much you can do to improve this (may a database load?). Good luck.

Comment: Finally, `awk` can slow things down when you recast your `$0` with statements like `$0=$37,$62,$23,$10,$53,$57,$68,$26,$52,$4,$38,$5,$24` (which you are **not** doing). But it might be worth a test of keeping those field numbers in order and send that data to the sort, then reorder after sorted. so `print $4,$5,$10,....` which of course, whould required you to change your `sort -k*n* ...` keys. Just an idea! Good luck.

Comment: What is "gsort" can you get away with using GNUCoreutils sort? Have you considered using "cut" instead of awk; it **maybe** faster because you aren't using any awk features other than extraction?

Comment: @NinjaGaiden `gsort` is the GNU Coreutils sort, except on a mac when you install it via Homebrew they all get `g-` prefix to not to be confused with system defaults. The point about cut is valid, and a good one, it does make a significant difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I open-sourced a tool for tab delimited files that improves on the speed of awk for the filtering step. The tool is [tsv-select](https://ebay.github.io/tsv-utils/docs/tool_reference/tsv-select.html), it's part of eBay's [tsv utilities toolkit](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils). Performance comparison to different awk implementations is [here](https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils/blob/master/docs/comparative-benchmarks-2017.md#column-selection-benchmark). The equivalent to the awk call is

```
$ tsv-select -f 37,62,23,10,53,57,68,26,52,4,38,5,24 ../ck_data/big.txt
```

Another avenue you could try is to consider alternate versions of awk. In my tests I've found mawk to be materially faster than other versions of awk for this task. See the benchmarks page listed above. (Note: The version of awk shipped with Mac OS X is very slow. gawk (gnu awk) is quite bit faster. It's available via macports or homebrew.)

Comment: very cool. Thanks for sharing. @posdef, be sure to read section `Set the buffer size for reading from standard input` at JonDeg's https://github.com/eBay/tsv-utils-dlang/blob/master/docs/TipsAndTricks.md . Good luck.